# returning array of character pointer in C

Tags: c, pointers

I am using below function to convert Decimal to binary

```
char** DEtoBinary(char HexDE[])
{
    printf("HexDE = %s\n", HexDE);
    int I;
    char* deBinary[16];
    for (I = 0; I <= 15; I++)
    {
        //deBinary = deBinary + Hex2Binary(HexDE.Substring(I, 1));
        deBinary[I] = strcpy(deBinary, Hex2Binary(substring_added1(HexDE, I, 1)));

    }
    printf("deBinary = %s\n", deBinary);
    return deBinary;

}
```

Hex to binary function

```
char *Hex2Binary(char* DE)
{
    printf("Inside DE = %s\n", DE);

    char *myBinary;
    long val = strtol(DE, NULL, 16);

    switch(val)
    {
        case 0:
         myBinary = "0000";
         break;

        case 1:
         myBinary = "0001";
         break;

        case 2:
         myBinary = "0010";
         break;

        case 3:
         myBinary = "0011";
         break;

        case 4:
         myBinary = "0100";
         break;

        case 5:
         myBinary = "0101";
         break;

        case 6:
         myBinary = "0110";
         break;

        case 7:
         myBinary = "0111";
         break;

        case 8:
         myBinary = "1000";
         break;

        case 9:
         myBinary = "1001";
         break;

        case 10: //A
         myBinary = "1010";
         break;

        case 11: //B
         myBinary = "1011";
         break;

        case 12://C
         myBinary = "1100";
         break;

        case 13://D
         myBinary = "1101";
         break;

        case 14://E
         myBinary = "1110";
         break;

        case 15: //F
         myBinary = "1111";
         break;

    }
    printf("myBinary = %s\n" ,myBinary);
    return myBinary;
 }
```

In Hex2Binary function,
myBinary is returning properly, but I need to send whole binary converted string to original caller of char* DEtoBinary(char HexDE[])

original caller is

```
de1Binary = DEtoBinary(DE[0]);
```

Example 
my DE[0] = E234567787888888

Expected is 111000100011...........
But I am getting only binary value of last hex value i.e. 8 is 1000

Comment: The code for DEtoBinary shall not even compile. Your function return type is `char*` and you are returning a `char**`

Comment: Your posted code contains too many inconsistencies like `char **` of Hex2Binary which returns `char*`,  `deBinary[I] = strcpy` and `strcpy(char**, char**)`;. Please post the actual code. I don't understand how comes that it works for you in any case.

Comment: It is compiling. But wrong from my side.I corrected to char*.I will edit in my original post

Comment: Have you put the warnings on. There are so may bugs in this code. Use of `strcpy`. Returning stuff that is one the stack and therefore goes out of scope....

Comment: Voted to close. Post something we can compile.

Comment: I think there is some problem with your compiler, if you can post all of your code on ideone.com and if it works then share the link as well, I guess

Comment: I written all code above in my original post. My DEtoBinary function need to return complete binary string in DE[0] = "1110", DE[1] = "0010" ....

Comment: @user2357643 my very first comment still holds true.`deBinary` is an array of pointers and hence a of type `char**` and the original function has the return type as `char*` hence this doesn't compile.

Comment: @user007 I corrected that mistake still same problem

Comment: http://ideone.com/LLZwaA read the last error in the link.

Comment: I corrected in my original post as well my code in my system.Still getting same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Few things which I still see wrong are ::

```
deBinary[I] = strcpy(deBinary, Hex2Binary(substring_added1(HexDE, I, 1)));
```

You are again copying a `char*` to a `char**` which is not a good idea. Probably you shall try something like ::

```
strcpy(deBinary[I], Hex2Binary(substring_added1(HexDE, I, 1)));
```

Check this :: [strcpy() return value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561427/strcpy-return-value)

So, I don't think there is any need to save the value returned by `strcpy`.

Moreover, in your print statement you print

```
printf("deBinary = %s\n", deBinary);
```

where `deBinary` is again a `char**` :P
But, from what I understand, that it only prints first 4 binary digits is because it encounters `\0` at the end of the first binary representation.

So, probably you shall try to do::

```
for(int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
    printf("%s ", deBinary[i]);
}
```

This, might actually solve your problem.

Moreover, in your code, you declare something like this, `char* deBinary[16];`, which is an array of 16 `char*` which are meant to store the address of 16 `char` arrays, but infact you use `strcpy` to copy the string returned from `Hex2Binary` to the location pointed by `deBinary[i]`, which has not been allocated any memory, so you are copying characters to memory you never allocated, which is a bad idea (but might work on your device), so it is advisable either you declare your `deBinary` as `char deBinary[16][5]` or, instead of using `strcpy`, simply copy the address returned by `Hex2Binary` like

```
deBinary[i] = Hex2Binary( ... );
```

Because as far as I know, when you declare something like `"1100"` to a `char*` that is allocated to the constant memory, and might work. (I am not sure about this, if someone can comment about this and help it would be great).

I wish this could help!

**EDIT ::**

Moreover, talking again about the `deBinary[]`, you have locally declared a `char**` and returning it from the function, which is wrong since after a function call gets over, all the variables declared are scrapped since the function call gets out of the stack! So, if you do not need the converted array in the `main`, you can try changing the type of the function to `void`. Or else, try dynamically allocating `deBinary` or else allocating itself in the `main` and passing it as a parameter to the function `DEtoBinary`.

Answer (score -1):

You have confused something about `char *` and `char **`;
The return type of `Hex2Binary(char*)` is `char **`, but you return a `char *`;
The return type of `DEtoBinary(char[])` is `char *`, but you return a `char **`;

Remember:

`char *val` is same as `char valp[]`;

`char *val[]` is same as `char **val`;

Comment: Yes I noticed my mistake.