# Copy a byte to another register in GNU C inline asm, where the compiler chooses registers for both operands

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, x86, inline-assembly

I'm trying to mess around with strings in inline asm for c. I was able to understand how strcpy works (shown below):

```c
static inline char *strcpy(char *dest, char *src)
{
  int d0, d1, d2;
  char temp;

  asm volatile(
    "loop:  lodsb;"   /* load value pointed to by %si into %al, increment %si */
    "       stosb;"   /* move %al to address pointed to by %di, increment %di */
    "       testb %%al, %%al;"
    "       jne loop;"
    : "=&S" (d0), "=&D" (d1), "=&a" (d2)
    : "0" (src), "1" (dest)
    : "memory"
  );
}
```

I'm trying to use this structure to make it so I can modify individual characters of the string before returning them. As a result I'm attempting something that looks like:

```c
static inline char *strcpy(char *dest, char *src)
{
  int d0, d1, d2;
  char temp;

  asm volatile(
    "loop:  lodsb;"   /* load value pointed to by %si into %al, increment %si */
    "       mov %2, %3;" /* move al into temp */
    /*
     *
     * Do and comparisons and jumps based off how I want to change the characters
     *
     */
    "       stosb;"   /* move %al to address pointed to by %di, increment %di */
    "       testb %%al, %%al;"
    "       jne loop;"
    : "=&S" (d0), "=&D" (d1), "=&a" (d2), "+r" (temp)
    : "0" (src), "1" (dest)
    : "memory"
  );
}
```

Where I'm basically moving the byte put into `%al` by the `lodsb` instruction into a temp variable where I do any processing after. However, it seems that the character is never actually stored in temp for some reason I cannot figure out.

Comment: BTW, your first version of `strcpy` looks safe and correct, nice.  You could simplify with `"+S"(src)` because you're inside a wrapper function (so it's ok to modify this function's local `src`) but dummy output with matching constraint is the canonical way to take an input in a register you want to destroy.  Of course it's not particularly *efficient* to use lodsb/stosb in a loop, especially on CPUs that don't rename AL separately from RAX so every load also needs an ALU uop to merge into RAX.  But byte-at-a-time is much worse than you can do with SSE2 so let's ignore performance.

Answer (score 2):

Your 2nd version won't even assemble because `temp` and `d2` are different sizes, so you end up with `mov %eax, %dl` from GCC: https://godbolt.org/z/tng4g4.  **When inline asm doesn't do what you want, always look at the compiler-generated asm** to see what the compiler actually substituted into your template (and what registers it picked for which operand).

This doesn't match what you describe (runs but doesn't work) so it's not a MCVE of exactly what you were doing.  But the real question is still answerable.

**One easy way is to declare both C temporaries the same size so GCC picks the same width registers.**

Or you can use size overrides like `mov %k2, %k3` to get `movl` or `mov %b2, %b3` to get `movb` (8-bit operand-size).

Strangely you chose `int` for the `"=a"` temporary so the compiler picks EAX, even though you only load a `char`.

I'd actually recommend `movzbl %2b, %3k` to use the opposite sizes from how you declared the variables; that's more efficient than merging a byte into the low byte of the destination, and avoids introducing (or adding more) partial-register problems on P6-family, early Sandybridge-family, *and* CPUs that don't do any partial-register renaming.  Plus, Intel since Ivybridge can do mov-elimination on it.

---

BTW, your first version of strcpy looks safe and correct, nice.  And yes, the `"memory"` clobber is necessary.

Err, at least the inline asm is correct.  **You have C undefined behaviour from falling off the end of a non-`void` function without a `return` statement, though.**

You could simplify the asm operands with a `"+&S"(src)` read/write operand instead of a dummy output because you're inside a wrapper function (so it's ok to modify this function's local `src`).  Dummy output with matching constraint is the canonical way to take an input in a register you want to destroy, though.

(If you want to work like [ISO C's poorly-designed `strcpy`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561427/strcpy-return-value), you'd want `char *retval = dst` ahead of the asm statement, if you're going to use the above suggestion of `"+S"` and `"+D"` operands.  A better idea would be to call it `stpcpy` and return a pointer to the *end* of the destination.  Also, your src should be `const char*`.)

**Of course it's not particularly efficient to use lodsb/stosb in a loop**, especially on CPUs that don't rename AL separately from RAX so every load also needs an ALU uop to merge into RAX. But byte-at-a-time is much worse than you can do with SSE2 so optimizing this with `movzx` loads, and maybe an indexed addressing mode is probably not worth the trouble.  See https://agner.org/optimize/ and other optimization links in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info, especially https://uops.info/ for instruction latency / throughput / uop count.  (`stosb` is 3 uops vs. 2 total for a `mov` store + `inc edi`.)

If you're actually optimizing for code-size over speed, just use 8-bit or 32-bit `mov` to copy registers, not `movzbl`.

---

BTW, with this many operands, you probably want to use named operands like `[src] "+&S"(src)` in the constraints, and then `%[src]` in the template.

Comment: Hey, so I tried using size overrides to adjust my registers so they all have the same value with `mov %b2, %3;` and I also changed the output type of %eax to be a char instead of an int with `"=&a" (ret)` and it seemed to have properly modified the register size (instruction in compiler-generated asm looks like `mov %al, %cl`). So by my understand of your explanation, there shouldn't be an issue with the data and register size. However, I am still unable to execute a compare instruction against this register with an arbitrary hexadecimal value (`cmp 0x70, %3`).

Comment: @Tom: `0x70` is a memory operand with absolute address `0x70`.  You want something like `cmp $0x70, %%al`.  (No need to copy before branching, you might only need to read it; only bother with that in the `if` body if you need a 2nd copy.  You know lodsb wrote AL, and you know you used a dummy output to tell the compiler about EAX specifically, so you might as well write normal-looking asm that uses that register name explicitly instead of an operand number.  BTW, a clobber on `%eax` would work, too, if you don't care about reading the value outside the asm statement.)