# Why does fopen() use strings instead of enums?

Tags: c, string, enums, fopen

In C, to specify how you open a file, you use a string, like `"r"`, `"w"`, etc. Why not an `enum`? Enums can be used with a switch statement, so then they would run a lot faster. Just why does `fopen` use a string instead of an `enum`? The question is simple.

Comment: But the file mode is not simply one character - there are multiple combinations allowed, like "wb" or "ta+".

Comment: @AdrianMole Are you giving OP fuel? Those are most likely compiletime optimizations anyway.

Comment: The question is essentially unanswerable; it was a decision made in the mid to late 70s that has persisted ever since.  The `open()` call of that era was very simple with very few options; it now has a myriad options (POSIX [`open()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/open.html) lists 18 options).  Strings are very flexible and more easily extended if that's necessary, but of course the standard doesn't change much (check out Annex K of C11 [§K.3.5.2.1 The `fopen_s` function](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#K.3.5.2.1)).

Comment: @Ted Actually, I voted-to-close (opinion-based) when I came across this in the F/P Review queue! However, there is something a bit more subtle about the "mode" string (see posted answer).

Comment: "a lot faster" is a misunderstanding. There are multiple orders of magitude between the possible performance difference here and the time cost of the operation `fopen` performs.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler in fact the question is answerable based on e.g. C99 rationale (see my answer); your comment has a hint.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler lol, you've written an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2523898/918959) to this already.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala — I don't remember every answer I've written, I'm afraid — ten years on SO is a long time!

Answer (score 0):

Because `fopen` can be called with a combination of flags, example:

```
FILE *fp = fopen("MyFile", "wb+");
```

You can achieve something similar by `|`'ing together binary flags, an alternate interface might look like this:

```
FILE *fp = fopen("MyFile", F_WRITE | F_BINARY | F_UPDATE);
```

Or something like that, but that's rather clunkier than using a string isn't it?

In any case, enums aren't suitable because you'd have to have a unique enum for every possible combination of options, which is *definitely* clunkier and harder to code an implementation for.

Comment: No, you don't have to have separate enums for each possible combination; you can use `enum { O_RDONLY = 0, O_WRONLY = 1, O_RDWR = 2, O_EXCL = 4, O_TRUNC = 8, … };` and then combine those values as you showed.  Note that `O_RDONLY` is traditionally 0 and is not combinable with `O_WRONLY` to get `O_RDWR`, but the rest of the values associated with `open()` could be an enumeration — except that POSIX requires that the _values shall be bitwise-distinct and shall be suitable for use in `#if` preprocessing directives_ and enumerations are not suitable for `#if`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I interpreted the question to mean "Why don't we just enumerate the possible mode inputs?" Yes you can implement flags using an enum, and in fact that's usually the best way.

Comment: @nickelpro posix `open` has this interface, so not only it is possible, but it is implemented on one of the most prevalent APIs